# how can i add a timestamp as an extra column to my dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, immutability, rdd

*Hi all,

I have an easy question for you all.
 I have an RDD, created from kafka streaming using createStream method.
Now i want to add a timestamp as a value to this rdd before converting in to dataframe.
I have tried doing  to add a value to the dataframe using with withColumn() but returning this error*

```
val topicMaps = Map("topic" -> 1)
    val now = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime()

    val messages = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaConf, topicMaps, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)

      messages.foreachRDD(rdd =>
          {

            val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
            import sqlContext.implicits._

            val dataframe = sqlContext.read.json(rdd.map(_._2))



        val d =dataframe.withColumn("timeStamp_column",dataframe.col("now"))
```

> val d =dataframe.withColumn("timeStamp_column",dataframe.col("now"))
>           org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "now" among (action, device_os_ver, device_type, event_name,
>   item_name, lat, lon, memberid, productUpccd, tenantid);
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:15

As i came to know that DataFrames cannot be altered as they are immutable, but RDDs are immutable as well.
Then what is the best way to do it.
How to a value to the RDD(adding timestamp to an RDD dynamically).

Comment: where have you defined the dataframe c? can you add its schema?

Comment: sorry, c is the dataframe. Let me correct it.I was in a hurry.

Answer (score 18):

Try current_timestamp function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.current_timestamp    
df.withColumn("time_stamp", current_timestamp())
```

Comment: I got the solution written above but if I want to change it to string how can do that. current_timestamp() //org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ df.withColumn("time_stamp", lit(current_timestamp())) I tried df.withColumn("time_stamp", lit(current_timestamp()).cast(string) I tried cast as string but non of them working for me.

Comment: @VivekKumar you should use sql data types not scala string type org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.StringType

Comment: below code worked for me                                                 
    withColumn("curr_date", lit(current_timestamp().cast(StringType))).

Comment: `error: not found: value lit`, `error: not found: value current_timestamp` if this needs an imported library, please include it in the code

Comment: I'm wondering if in this approach each executor might have a different ts (as ts will be calculated locally on each executor) or the value will be same among all executor ?

Comment: yes you are correct Soheil ... timestamp should be calculated FIRST and then passed as a value otherwise there will be differences in deed.

Answer (score 4):

For add a new column with a constant like timestamp, you can use `lit`function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newDF = oldDF.withColumn("timeStamp_column", lit(System.currentTimeMillis))
```

Comment: Hi Javier, But this code is giving me an headache, sometimes it is printing the schema and sometimes it is throwing this

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:221) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedStar.expand(unresolved.scala:199) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfu

Comment: Hi Jack, this is strange, what version of Spark are you using? This is an example tested in spark-shell 1.6.3:

`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`
`val oldDF=sc.parallelize(Seq((1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1))).toDF`
`oldDF.show`
`val newDF = oldDF.withColumn("timeStamp_column", lit(System.currentTimeMillis))`
`newDF.show`
I'm also using Spark 2.1 and is working too.

Comment: yes it works fine in the spark shell, but throws the above error while using this code in spark streaming application.I'm using spark 1.6.1 with java 1.7

Comment: shall i need to import any other package to make it happen?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. I usually perform a write after this.

```
val d = dataframe.withColumn("SparkLoadedAt", current_timestamp())
```

Comment: `error: not found: value current_timestamp` what am I missing? I've been trying to get databricks scala to do this for hours.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, you will have to import the function
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.current_timestamp

Answer (score 1):

In Scala/Databricks:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newDF = oldDF.withColumn("Timestamp",current_timestamp())
```

[See my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPyAZ.png)

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Comment: See my other comments.... this is the only actual code that doesn't throw the error `error: not found: value current_timestamp` so in my opinion this should be the answer as the other code doesn't function

Answer (score 0):

I see in comments that some folks are having trouble getting the timestamp to string.  Here is a way to do that using spark 3 datetime format

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val d =dataframe. 
  .withColumn("timeStamp_column", date_format(current_timestamp(), "y-M-d'T'H:m:sX"))
```